# Python parse GET|POST path from access logs

Tags: python, regex

Suppose we have some access logs like this

> 83.198.250.175 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:40:06 +0100] "GET **/images/ht1.gif** HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "http://www.facades.fr/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Wanadoo 6.7; Orange 8.0)" "-"
>
> 65.33.94.190 - - [05/Apr/2003:17:26:27 -0500] "POST **/samples/dem/tt.php**?x=e2323 HTTP/1.0" 404 276
>
> 151.227.152.48 - - [02/Jul/2014:14:35:55 +0100] "GET **/css/main.css** HTTP/1.1" 200 4658 "http://stanmore.menczykowski.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
>
> 10.143.2.119 64.103.161.112 - [06/Jan/1970:00:48:01 +0000] "GET **/right_arrow.jpg** HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://64.103.161.112/index_eth_diag.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"

I need to get the bolded text parts after *POST* and *GET* (path to files).
the log format may be vary but the request type and path will always exist.

I tried to with the following but It didn't always work because the log format not the same

```
parts = [
    r'(?P<host>\S+)',                   # host %h
    r'\S+',                             # indent %l (unused)
    r'(?P<user>\S+)',                   # user %u
    r'\[(?P<time>.+)\]',                # time %t
    r'"(?P<request>.*)"',               # request "%r"
    r'(?P<status>[0-9]+)',              # status %>s
    r'(?P<size>\S+)',                   # size %b (careful, can be '-')
    r'"(?P<referrer>.*)"',              # referrer "%{Referer}i"
    r'"(?P<agent>.*)"',                 # user agent "%{User-agent}i"
]

def get_structured_access_logs_list(access_logs):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s+'.join(parts) + r'\s*\Z')

    # Initialize required variables
    log_data = []

    # Get components from each line of the log file into a structured dict
    for line in access_logs:
        try:
            log_data.append(pattern.match(line).groupdict())
        except:
            pass
    return log_data

def parse_path(request_string) :
    rx = re.compile(r'^(?:GET|POST)\s+([^?\s]+).*$', re.M)
    return rx.findall(request_string)


def get_file_paths(access_logs_list):
    file_path_set = set()
    for dict in access_logs_list:
        if 'request' in dict.keys():
            file_name = parse_path(dict['request'])[0] # passing a single line, the list will contain only 1 element
            if file_name is not None:
                file_path_set.add(full_path)
    return accessed_file_set
```

UPDATE: 
after adjusting the code, the function 'get_file_paths' will return a set contains full path to files accessed in access logs

```
def parse_path(request_string) :
    rx = re.compile(r'"(?:GET|POST)\s+([^\s?]*)', re.M)
    return rx.findall(request_string)


def get_file_paths(access_logs):
    file_set = set()
    for line in access_logs:
            matches = parse_accessed_file_name_list(line) # passing a single line, the list will contain only 1 element
            if matches is None or len(matches) <= 0:
                continue
            full_path = root_path + matches[0]
            if os.path.isfile(full_path):
                file_set.add(full_path)
    return file_set
```

Comment: See the full solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491666/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your regex is very generic (you use `\S` and `.` that are very broad), why don't you use directly:

```
"(?:GET|POST)\s+([^\s?]*)
```

`[^\s?]` matches all the characters that are not spaces nor question marks.

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/e3qZbB/1) a demo.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(?x)^
    (?P<host>\S+)                         \s+         # host %h
    \S+                                   \s+         # indent %l (unused)
    (?P<user>\S+)                         \s+         # user %u
    \[(?P<time>.*?)\]                     \s+         # time %t
    "\S+\s+(?P<request>[^"?\s]*)[^"]*"    \s+         # request "%r"
    (?P<status>[0-9]+)                    \s+         # status %>s
    (?P<size>\S+)                      (?:\s+         # size %b (careful, can be '-')
    "(?P<referrer>[^"?\s]*[^"]*)"         \s+         # referrer "%{Referer}i"
    "(?P<agent>[^"]*)"                 (?:\s+         # user agent "%{User-agent}i"
    "[^"]*"                            )? )?          # unused
$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2A4GR/1).

There are a lot of minor improvements I introduced (see `[^"]*` instead of `.*`), the major ones are *optional non-capturing groups* to match referrer and agent fields that may be missing and the `request` pattern that looks like `(?P<request>[^"?\s]*)` and only captures 0 or more chars other than whitespace, `?` and `"` char,while the subsequent `[^"]*"` matches the rest of the field.

Also, it makes sense to compile the pattern *once*, not as you do it when processing each line.

The `(?x)` modifier enables the free spacing mode making it possible to format the pattern on multiple lines and add comments.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/LqD8DJ):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"""(?x)^
    (?P<host>\S+)                         \s+         # host %h
    \S+                                   \s+         # indent %l (unused)
    (?P<user>\S+)                         \s+         # user %u
    \[(?P<time>.*?)\]                     \s+         # time %t
    "\S+\s+(?P<request>[^"?\s]*)[^"]*"    \s+         # request "%r"
    (?P<status>[0-9]+)                    \s+         # status %>s
    (?P<size>\S+)                      (?:\s+          # size %b (careful, can be '-')
    "(?P<referrer>[^"?\s]*[^"]*)"         \s+         # referrer "%{Referer}i"
    "(?P<agent>[^"]*)"                 (?:\s+         # user agent "%{User-agent}i"
    "[^"]*"                           )?)?            # optional argument (unused)
$""")

def get_structured_access_logs_list(access_logs):
    # Initialize required variables
    log_data = []
    # Get components from each line of the log file into a structured dict
    for line in access_logs:
        try:
            log_data.append(pattern.match(line).groupdict())
        except:
            pass
    return log_data

lines = ['83.198.250.175 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:40:06 +0100] "GET /images/ht1.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "http://www.facades.fr/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Wanadoo 6.7; Orange 8.0)" "-"',
'65.33.94.190 - - [05/Apr/2003:17:26:27 -0500] "POST /samples/dem/tt.php?x=e2323 HTTP/1.0" 404 276',
'151.227.152.48 - - [02/Jul/2014:14:35:55 +0100] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4658 "http://stanmore.menczykowski.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"',
'10.143.2.119 64.103.161.112 - [06/Jan/1970:00:48:01 +0000] "GET /right_arrow.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://64.103.161.112/index_eth_diag.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"']
for res in get_structured_access_logs_list(lines):
    print(res)
```

Comment: @Salama Note that your `r'"(?P<referrer>.*)"'` and `r'"(?P<agent>.*)"'` yield wrong output if you have  3 or more `"..."` fields at the end of the line. You cannot use your approach with dynamic pattern building easily as you have optional fields, thus, I think the free-spacing regex with comments is a more flexible approach here that helps keep the same level of readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex and get the path from group1,

```
^.*?"(?:GET|POST) ([^\s?]+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cXgrLH/2)**